# Mysql tls secure connection with c# client

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssl

I tried to establish secure connection between c# app and mysql 8.0.26 server and it worked locally ...
When i run my app on the same site as mysql server it works great !
But when i transfer my app to other machine on the same network it fails maybe two or times but then it runs okay and retrieve the data , im so confused why is that. I ll paste logs of the exception and my code of connection

```
 //originally existed in app.xaml.cs
```

````
public static string ServerConnection
        {
            get
            {
                 return String.Format("server=" + App.host + ";uid=" + App.username + ";password=" + App.password + ";database=" + App.dbname + ";allow user variables=true;charset=utf8;SSLMODE=VERIFYCA;SslCa=ssl/ca.pem; ");
         }
        }

 public ObservableCollection<PersonClassName> getComboTxtFromDB()
        {
            ObservableCollection<PersonClassName> _allPersons = new ObservableCollection<PersonClassName>();
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ServerConnection))
            {
                try
                {
                     conn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + App.domainAndUsername + " at " + App.host + "  from  conn.Open() " + ex);
                }
                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT personAge FROM tbl_person";
                    using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while ( dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            _allPersons.Add(new PersonClassName { Age = Convert.ToString(dataReader["personAge"]) });
                        }
                    }
                }        
            }
            return _allPersons;       
        }
        ```

    Authentication to host '192.168.1.32' for user 'ssluser' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Got timeout reading communication packets ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Got timeout reading communication packets
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   à MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at ORG.Models.PersonClassName.getComboTxtFromDB() in C:\Users\*****\Desktop\ORG app\ORG\Models\PersonClassName.cs:line 488 
   
 Time:2022-05-30 08:51:59,394 thread ID: [4] Log level:ERROR Error class:ORG.Models.PersonClassName Error Description:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[ORG.Models.PersonClassName] getComboTxtFromDB()test at 127.0.0.1 from   conn.Open() MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'ssluser' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed. 
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. 
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. 
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
 
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at ORG.Models.PersonClassName.getComboTxtFromDB() in 



C:\Users\*****\Desktop\ORG app\ORG\Models\PersonClassName.cs:line 488
````

Comment: Looks like something is messing up th TLS/SSL secure connection. Perhaps a firewall or antivirus is decrypting it and messing it up, or perhaps the revocation check is taking too long. Check both server and client. There are other possible issues, but it does appear to be TLS related

Comment: I checked the firewall , i even connected them directly using network cable... same problem , i dont know if there is a setting that i missed ..